# How to start programming something like mohiomap?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angularjs

I'm thinking about creating a mindmap webapp for my own purpouses. 
I would like to incorporate a layout like they do at https://www.moh.io/mohiomap/welcome.php.

Can anybody give me any hints on how to start at something like this?

Regards,

Roel

Comment: Mohiomap uses a "force directed" diagram. Need to search for that keyword. You will find stuff like arbor.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the UI there is an awesome looking project called JSPlumb. It helps you visually connect nodes in a nice way

JSPlumb website:
http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/home/jquery.html

A mind map is basically just a list of lists... I would start by creating a list view first and implement methods to add and remove items. This could be done with nested html ul elements. Once this works you can style the ul elements to look like "nodes" and connect them with JSPlumb.